# AWS S3 $folder$ creating how to rectify

Tags: amazon-web-services

As per schedule my `datapipeline(DynamoDB_Export-to-QuickSight)` runs daily one time @ 2:00 28 UTC time and places a success file in `#{myOutputS3Loc}/dynamoDB/#{format(@scheduledStartTime, 'YYYY-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss')}`.

But before this schedule daily @ 7:00:21 AM GMT+0530  and empty file is being created in the same folder. As this empty folder is being created before my datapipeline is throwing an error that file already exits.

If I delete that $folder$ file which is empty before my scheduled datapipe line it is executing successfully. But daily I can not manually delete the file right.

I am not sure why this empty $folder$ is being created daily before 12 hours to my scheduled time.

Answer (score 0):

A `$folder$` file is typically created by application that wish a folder to 'appear' in an Amazon S3 bucket.

Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3 — it is a flat object store. Directories will automatically appear when a file is copied to a location that includes a path.

However, some application specifically want a folder to appear, so they create an empty file, which causes the folder to appear (sort of) when the bucket is listed.

Thus, you'll need to track-down what application is creating the folder. It might be part of your pipeline job, or it might be from somewhere else. You could look at the Creation timestamp to determine when it is created and what is probably creating it.

Comment: Hi John Thank you very much for your help. I will check what job is being run during that time stamp.Appreciated your help once again,,,,

Comment: Hi John I tried to check which job is executing at that particular time but i could not able to debug. Can you please guide me which way or process do i need to track out which process/job is executing at that particular time. I mean do i need to search in EMR masternode logs etc. Please help. thanks in advance..

Comment: I do not know what your systems are, nor what they are doing, so I cannot provide any advice on how to track this down.